# swagger path $ref for OPTIONS requests

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I want to construct an API gateway deployment from a swagger.yml file.  I need to support CORS for all endpoints.  All my `options` path definitions are exactly the same.  How do I define the `options` path one place and `$ref` it where I want to use it?

I was hoping to do something like this (note the `$ref: '#/definitions/CorsOptions'` at the same level as `get`):

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "2016-10-26T03:15:31Z"
  title: "corstest"
host: ""
basePath: ""
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /page:
    get:
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234:function:myLambdaFunc/invocations"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "GET"
        type: "aws_proxy"
    $ref: '#/definitions/CorsOptions'
definitions:
  Empty:
    type: "object"
    title: "Empty Schema"
  CorsOptions:
    options:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
            Cache-Control:
              type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        type: "mock"
```

This yaml does not pass [swagger validation](http://bigstickcarpet.com/swagger-parser/www/index.html).  How can I pull off what I'm trying to do so my yaml file is not huge and bloated with the same `options` path definition.

The [swagger spec](http://swagger.io/specification/#pathItemObject) supports `$ref` as a `path item object` however I can't figure out where I can put that definition of the path item object.  I think API Gateway swagger import restricts pulling `yaml` files from other places but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will work.  API Gateway currently only supports $ref for models and schemas, not for arbitrary objects.  We have a backlog item to support $ref in more places, so we might add support for this eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to specify `$ref` values in arbitrary places, you can use the [expand-swagger-refs](https://github.com/duncanhall/expand-swagger-refs) module.

This will take a Swagger schema as an input, and automatically inline all your $ref values, giving you back a schema that is suitable for use with API gateway.

It is available on the command line with support for `stdin` and `stdout`:

```
swagger-expand < my-complex-schema.json > aws-compatible.json
```

And also as an importable Node module:

```
const { expand, expanded } = require('expand-swagger-refs');
const schema = require('./api/swagger.json');

// Create a copy of the schema, with $ref values expanded: 
const expandedSchema = expanded(schema);

// Or expand the schema object in-place (mutates the object):
expand(schema)
```